# What is the most efficient way to retrieve the single most recent record by date given certain other criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Given a table which has some fields as its composite key, along with a date, I need to find the record matching all fields except the date, which precedes the date. There is a unique index over all fields. There may be 1000+ records which match on the key, but I only need the one immediately preceding the date.

Previously, the system inserted a row on every day, so we could just access the record for date - 1 which is a direct lookup. However, this is leading to exponential growth in the database and cannot be continued (we are now over 500M rows and only really need ~700k of those).

As an example, this is a boiled-down version the current query:

```
select
    i.quantity
from inventory i
where i.inventory_date = :inventory_date - 1
and   i.company_id = :company_id
and   i.client_id = :client_id
and   i.product_id = :product_id;
```

And this is what I had intended to change it to. Unfortunately, the above query runs in linear time (single-row lookup on a unique index) whereas the below takes every row before doing the filtering (range scan on the unique index). In real world terms, we're talking hundreths of a second versus up to ten seconds.

```
select
    quantity,
    inventory_date
from (
    select
        i.quantity,
        i.inventory_date,
        max(i.inventory_date) over (partition by i.company_id, i.client_id, i.product_id) max_inv_date
    from inventory i
    where i.inventory_date < :inventory_date
    and   i.company_id = :company_id
    and   i.client_id = :client_id
    and   i.product_id = :product_id
)
where inventory_date = max_inv_date;
```

Is there a better (or at least, better-performing) way to write the above query?

Comment: What order are the fields in your key/index? Is the date column indexed ascending or descending in the composite? What does the execution plan show, for the old and new query? I'm unclear why the old way is no longer performant if it is still hitting a unique index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first query:

```
select i.quantity
from inventory i
where i.inventory_date = :inventory_date - 1
and   i.company_id = :company_id
and   i.client_id = :client_id
and   i.product_id = :product_id;
```

The best index is `inventory(company_id, client_id, product_id, inventory_date, quantity)`.  The first three elements of the index can be in a different order.  And, other columns can be added *after* the date.  For the index to be maximally useful, those three columns need to be first.  "Linear" lookup time is not expected for this query and not needed.

To get the most recent value for date, keep the same index and do:

```
select i.*
from (select i.quantity
      from inventory i
      where i.company_id = :company_id and
            i.client_id = :client_id and
            i.product_id = :product_id and
            i.inventory_date < :inventory_date
      order by i.inventory_date desc
     ) i
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: This works, thanks, but I'm unsure as to why you think quantity should be on the index? It's the data that we're trying to get out.

Comment: By having quantity in the index, you can avoid a TABLE ACCESS BY ROWID operation.

Comment: @Andrew . . . Tis is called a covering index for the query.  It means that the query can be processed entirely using the index, so the table's data pages don't need to be accessed.